# Why is the gaussian the least biased distribution when the first and second moments are given?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, calculus-of-variations, entropy

I know it's the least biased distribution because the entropy is maximized, but I was wondering how to prove that the gaussian maximizes the entropy.
When I formulate the problem is mathematical terms, it reduces to maximizing the integral from -inf to +inf of -f(x)log(f(x)) given some constraints.
Is this is a calculus of variations problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a calculus of variations problem. You can solve it using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Explain the connection you see, please, between least biased and entropy considerations in your question. Merci beaucoup!

Comment: @GReyes Ok, I will learn about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Aruralreader The second law of thermodynamics says that a system left to itself would settle down at max entropy. I understand entropy as the measure of randomness or the average surprise in a measurement. The second law makes sense in a physical way. So a real system having the given measured moments would be likely to be in the maximum entropy state. If we suppose it's in any other state, then we would have to assume it didn't reach equilibrium, and that introduces a bias. That's the way I understand it, and I would be grateful if someone points out the flaws of this argument, if any.